# ordering foreach loop in results

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hello I am looking to order my foreach loop.
The information I have found on the top use arrays and since I am using the get_term function, I am unsure how to add an order command.

this is my code, from what i have read online i should be able to use 'Orderby' => 'count' 'order' => 'DESC' but when I add that in nothing happens.

```
     <div class="category" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
          <h2>Popular Categories</h2>
          <?php
          $terms = get_terms('category'); /*Name Of category*/
           foreach (array_slice($terms, 0, 5)  as $term ):
           ?>

           <ul class="category-list">
           <li class="list-items" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
           <a href="#"><?php echo $term->name ;?>  </a> <span>(<?php echo $term->count ;?>)</span>
          </li>
          </ul>

           <?php
          endforeach;
          wp_reset_query();
           ?>
        </div>
```

I read that I might have to create another array. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress allows you to order the result directly in the `WP_Query`. Just pass an array to `the get_terms()` function and you should get what you want:

```
$args = array(
   'orderby'  => 'id',
   'order'    => 'DESC'
);
get_terms('category', $args);
```

Replace the `orderby` with the row you want it to order by.